# How to execute command like 'recoverLease' in Hadoop 2.6.4

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using Hadoop 2.6.4 and I have files in status 'openforwrite'. I got the solutions: run 'hdfs debug recoverLease' to recover the lease of the hdfs block files.(Features After Hadoop 2.7.0)

But in my hadoop version(2.6.4) I can't execute `recoverLease` commands. Is there any ideas to fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In some rare cases, files can be stuck in the OPENFORWRITE state in HDFS more than the default expiration time. If this happens, the data needs to be moved to a new inode to clear up the OPENFORWRITE status.

Solution
1) Stop all applications writing to HDFS.
2) Move the file temporarily to some other location.
`$ hdfs dfs -mv /Path_to_file /tmp/`

3) Copy the file back to its original location. This will force a new inode to be created and will clear up the OPENFORWRITE state
`$ hdfs dfs -cp /tmp/Path_to_file /Original/destination`

4) Once you have confirmed that the file is working correctly, remove the copied file from temp location.
`$ hdfs dfs -rm /tmp/Path_to_file`